# Understanding the ridge leverage scores sampling from an arXiv paper

Tags: python, sampling, kernel-trick, approximation, leverage

I give a try to read the arXiv paper [Distributed Adaptive Sampling for Kernel Matrix Approximation, Calandriello et al. 2017](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.10172.pdf). I got a code implementation where they compute ridge leverage scores sampling sequentially using this paper, $$\widetilde{\tau}_{t,i}=\frac{1-\epsilon}{\gamma}\left( k_{i,i}-\boldsymbol{k}_{t,i}^\top \overline{\boldsymbol{S}}(\overline{\boldsymbol{S}}\boldsymbol{K}_t\overline{\boldsymbol{S}}+\gamma\boldsymbol{I}_t)^{-1}\overline{\boldsymbol{S}}^\top\boldsymbol{k}_{t,i} \right)\tag1$$
Where, they define a column dictionary as a collection $I_t=\{(i,w_i)\}_{i=1}^t$, where the first term denotes the index of the column and $w_i$ its weight , which is set to zero for all columns that are not retained. And $\boldsymbol{S}_t$ is the weighted selection matrix. For detail information in **the section 3, Sequential RLS Sampling**. There they redefine the dictionary,

> a collection $I=\{i,\widetilde{p}_i,q_i\}$, where $i$ is the index of the column (consider as point $\boldsymbol{x}_i$), $\widetilde{p}_i$ tracks the probability used to sample it, and $q_i$ is the number of copies (multiplicity) of $i$.

Question: I didn't understand what they mean by the parameter $q_i$?

The code implementation to compute $\widetilde{\tau}_{t,i}$,

```py
def compute_tau(centers_dict: CentersDictionary,
                X: np.ndarray,
                similarity_func: callable,
                lam_new: float,
                force_cpu=False):
    """Given a previosuly computed (eps, lambda)-accurate dictionary, it computes estimates
    of all RLS using the estimator from Calandriello et al. 2017"""
    xp = __load_gpu_module(force_cpu)
    diag_norm = np.asarray(similarity_func.diag(X))
    # (m x n) kernel matrix between samples in dictionary and dataset X
    K_DU = xp.asarray(similarity_func(centers_dict.X, X))
    # the estimator proposed in Calandriello et al. 2017 is
    # diag(XX' - XX'S(SX'XS + lam*I)^(-1)SXX')/lam
    # here for efficiency we collect an S inside the inverse and compute
    # diag(XX' - XX'(X'X + lam*S^(-2))^(-1)XX')/lam
    # note that in the second term we take care of dropping the rows/columns of X associated
    # with 0 entries in S
    U_DD, S_DD, _ = np.linalg.svd(xp.asnumpy(similarity_func(centers_dict.X, centers_dict.X)
                                             + lam_new * np.diag(centers_dict.probs)))
    U_DD, S_root_inv_DD = __stable_invert_root(U_DD, S_DD)
    E = xp.asarray(S_root_inv_DD * U_DD.T)
    # compute (X'X + lam*S^(-2))^(-1/2)XX'
    X_precond = E.dot(K_DU)
    # the diagonal entries of XX'(X'X + lam*S^(-2))^(-1)XX' are just the squared
    # ell-2 norm of the columns of (X'X + lam*S^(-2))^(-1/2)XX'
    tau = (diag_norm - xp.asnumpy(xp.square(X_precond, out=X_precond).sum(axis=0))) / lam_new
    return tau
```

I failed to understand the link between the actual paper formula $(1)$ (which is mention inside [`compute_tau`](https://github.com/LCSL/bless/blob/1d385e761ecf39c96f1eb4f470816a4cd732291f/bless.py#L126) as `diag(XX' - XX'S(SX'XS + lam*I)^(-1)SXX')/lam`) and the code implementation of `compute_tau`.

Question: **"what is `X_precond` here and what svd decomposition doing here?"**

I create a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/LCSL/bless/issues/1) and also mailed to reach the author, but got no luck. It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could assist me in resolving this matter.

Comment: It looks like they're just implementing a numerically stable matrix inverse. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1939962/singular-value-decomposition-and-inverse-of-square-matrix or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884859/what-is-the-svd-of-a-1

Comment: I am interested to know it. Can you redirect me to any resource? @Sycorax